# How different model use same sign in page in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, pundit

This is my first rails app and I'm quite new to rails. I created a user model with devise, added roles(admin, owner) to the user model using pundit.

user.rb

```
    class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :owners, dependent: :destroy

  enum role: [:user, :owner, :agent, :admin]
  after_initialize :set_default_role, :if => :new_record?

  def set_default_role
    self.role ||= :user
  end

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

userpolicy:

```
    class UserPolicy
  attr_reader :current_user, :model

  def initialize(current_user, model)
    @current_user = current_user
    @user = model
  end

  def index?
    @current_user.admin?
  end

  def show?
    @current_user.admin? || @current_user == @user
  end

  def update?
    @current_user.admin?
  end

  def destroy?
    return false if @current_user == user
    @current_user.admin?
  end 
end
```

I created an owner model. A new owner is only created by admin role. Admin only adds the owner to owner model.  After admin adding the owner, owner-email and password are sent to owner email. with the given credentials owner login to his page. Here I want a login page for the owner to log into his page. I tried to use user's sign in page by an owner to login but I got error invalid username and password. is it possible to use user's sign in for owner, so that I'll only have a single login for admin/owner to log to their pages or I should create an another login page for an owner?

owner.rb:

```
    class Owner < ApplicationRecord
has_many :customers, dependent: :destroy
has_many :agents, dependent: :destroy
belongs_to :user

enum role: [:user, :owner]
after_initialize :set_default_role, :if => :new_record?

def set_default_role
  self.role ||= :owner
end

  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                      format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                      uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :mobile, presence: true, length: { maximum: 10 }
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }, allow_nil: true

  def Owner.digest(string)
    cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST :
                                                  BCrypt::Engine.cost
    BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
  end

end
```

my owner_policy:

```
    class OwnerPolicy
  attr_reader :current_user, :owner

  def initialize(current_user, owner)
    @current_user = current_user
    @owner = owner
  end

  def index?
    @current_user.admin?
  end

  def new?
    @current_user.admin?
  end

  def create?
    @current_user.admin?
  end

  def show?
    @current_user.admin? || @current_user == @owner
  end

  def edit?
    @current_user.admin? || @current_user == @owner
  end

  def update?
    @current_user.admin? || @current_user == @owner
  end

  def destroy?
    return false if @current_user == owner
    @current_user.admin?
  end
end
```

I googled and tried so many answers to achieve but it all ended up with a mess. it's taking me to rabbit hole by trying different answers. anyone, please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Does your `User` model have `username` and `password` which could be user for login for an `admin` or an `owner` ?

Comment: I'm confused by your database model. A `User` can be one of four types: `[:user, :owner, :agent, :admin]`. An `owner user` has many `owners`, and now you want to be able to log in as one of the `owners`??!!

Comment: Is this perhaps what you actually intended: `class Owner < User`, with `owner.role == :owner`. Now you only have one model for users (`User`).

Comment: agreed with @Tom Lord

Comment: Thank you for your response@TomLord. I'm agreeing with you but I have only few similar columns(like name, email, password) between user and owner. How do I add my remaining columns(like mobile,address.t.c.,) to owner if I inherit Owner < User.

Comment: @Nermin yes, my User model have username and password. To login as admin

Comment: @Sun Why can't non-owner users have a mobile number, address, etc? Those sound like perfectly sensible attributes for **all** users to have. But anyway, you could always separate those attributes out into another model(s) -- e.g. `User has_one :address`.

Comment: Thank you @TomLord. As I mentioned in my question admin only adds owner. Admin login into his page and can add/delete owners, I created a registration form to owner which adds owner to the owner model by admin. if I inherit Owner from User, the reg page will not be used and then how can admin adds owner. (different registration by different role but have a single login)

Comment: @Sun This brings us back to my original confusion: is an `owner` a **type of user** (you have it listed as a user `role`), or is it something that should be **associated with a user** (you have it listed as a `has_many` association)? I think it *should* be the former, which means your form is actually a **user creation** form -- and so inheriting from a `User` base class works fine.

Comment: Ok, let me clarify you here what I'm trying to achieve, leave it about user and owner association. My user - role admin has_many owner, owner belongs_to admin association. only admin can add/delete owner. has I explained in my question the credentials are sent to owner by mail, with that credentials owner can login and do his work. To do this I created User model using devise and assigned roles using pundit. I'm trying and wanted to make a single login where admin/owner/otheruser can login through redirect to their pages but it all ended up with a mess.

Comment: I still think you're mixed up about the basic data model... Why is there a default user role called `:user`? Why does an admin **have many owners**? (But I can imagine a use for the owner having an "inviter"?) I'll leave my sketch for how I think this should be structured below, but you need to figure out the basic data relationships properly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147676/discussion-between-sun-and-tom-lord).

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I think you should implement what you're *trying* to achieve:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # This is an **abstract** base class.
  # You should not create a `User` directly;
  # Only create Admin, Owner and Agent records

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }

  validates :name, presence: true,
                   length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true,
                    length: { maximum: 255 },
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :mobile, presence: true,
                     length: { maximum: 10 }
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, presence: true,
                       length: { minimum: 6 },
                       allow_nil: true

  def self.digest(string)
    cost = if ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost
             BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST
           else
             BCrypt::Engine.cost
           end
    BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
  end
end

class Admin < User
  # admin.type == 'Admin'
  # -- use the default column name for Single Table Inheritance.

  has_many :owners, dependent: :destroy
end

class Owner < User
  # owner.type == 'Owner'

  belongs_to :admin
  has_many :customers, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :agents, dependent: :destroy
end

class Agent < User
  # agent.type == 'Agent'

  # Add any agent-specific logic in here.
  # (This wasn't discussed in your original question)
end
```

You can now continue the inheritance pattern elsewhere - for example in you policies:

```
class OwnerPolicy < UserPolicy
```

And when signing in, you can always reference the `User` model - because all user types inherit from this.

Comment: Thank you @TomLord for your response. How can a admin adds Owner user

Comment: Here I'm confused, how to give different registration forms to different users it means as I mentioned only admin user can add/delete owner user, to add owner user there should be a form, so, that admin can add owner through the form. similarly owner only create agent user. I don't want a single form

Comment: let me clarify you one more thing is I don't have user role that I specified in my code. Roles  are only [:admin, :owner, :agent]. I have given that user role by referring some answers in stackoverflow that's it . I don't need of user role in it.

Comment: @sun I don't understand your problem here... If desired, you can have one form for creating/editing and `owner`, and another form for creating/editing an `agent`, and another form for creating editing an `admin`. You can have an `OwnersController`, with `OwnersController#new/create/edit/update` actions. Look up single table inheritance in rails, and follow the standard design pattern.